"Simple ideal" of a semigroup
I am working through Mario Petrich's Introduction to Semigroups.
Lemma I.3.11 states:
If I is a simple ideal of a semigroup S, then I is the kernel of S
The problem is that he has not defined "simple ideal," nor do I find this term defined straightforwardly through a Google or Stackexchange search. He has defined a "simple semigroup" (no proper ideals), and a "kernel" of a semigroup (the intersection of all ideals). Based on the proof that follows, it seems like it means a simple subsemigroup of S that is also an ideal of S (I was able to follow the proof with that definition).
Here is the proof:
If $J$ is an ideal of $S$, then $I \cap J \supseteq IJ$ and hence $I \cap J$ is
nonempty and is thus an ideal of $S$. But then $I \cap J$ is also an ideal of $I$,
which by simplicity of $I$ implies that $I \cap J = I$ and thus $I \subseteq J$.
So, is this use of "simple ideal" an editorial error in the text? Or is there another definition of "simple ideal" that I should be aware of?

Petrich certainly means an ideal that is also a simple semigroup.

I figured it out. Every ideal of a semigroup is a subsemigroup. Though the converse os not true. Author should have said this, though it's an easy proof.
